SQL importing XML with polish characters
Hi I wanted to import data from an xml file containing polish characters, but it fails. My xml file is in utf8 format and I’m positive it’s not the problem. Columns in my table are nvarchar and I can “insert into” polish characters but not with the script or import wizard. This is my script:
USE db name

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @xml = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), BulkColumn)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'path to xml file', SINGLE_CLOB) AS x;

DECLARE @hDoc INT;

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @xml;


INSERT INTO mytable (column)
SELECT 
    z.column
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/root/people/person', 2)
WITH (
    column NVARCHAR(50) 'column',
) AS z;

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc;

Tried changing databases xml files importing through different ways encoding xml nothing works for polish characters only insert into but I have many data can’t do it 1 by 1.

Which dbms are you using? The above SQL code is very product specific.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
(5) XML file sample

OPENXML(), and its companions sp_xml_preparedocument/sp_xml_removedocument is a proprietary Microsoft API. It is kept just for backward
compatibility with the obsolete SQL Server 2000. SQL Server 2005 onwards supports w3c's XQuery 1.0, XPath 2.0, and XSD 1.0.

I assume you are running the script inside SQL Server Management Studio.  If not, you should run with SSMS and check error messages which are better inside SSMS than with other tools.  You can also check the log files inside SSMS which in the explorer under Management to get better error messages.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
